# What word... (riddle)

Tags: riddle, word

There is a common English word that is nine letters long.

Each time you remove a letter from it, it still remains an English word - from nine letters right down to a single letter.

What is the original word, and what are the words that it becomes after removing one letter at a time?

Hint 1:

> The word before the letters are removed starts with the letter S.

Hint 2:

> the last letter of the word before letters are removed is g.

Resource: https://www.riddles.com/1005 and my friend

Comment: You said the hint in the puzzle itself as well...

Comment: I do believe that this puzzle was on Snopes a while back.  You probably should have cited https://www.snopes.com/language/puzzlers/9letters.asp

Comment: This question (in its many variations) is a regular one on this site, there are multiple solutions even with the clues, at least both ROT13(fpenccvat) and ROT13(fgnegyvat) work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One answer is

> STARTLING.

The words that can be made are:

> Starling, staring, string, sting, sing, sin, in, and I.

I suspect this is not the only answer though.  I'd be curious to see if anyone finds another...

Answer (score 6):

One word that fits the hints is...

> **startling**. Removing letters gives **starting**, **staring**, **string**, **sting**, **sing**, **sin**, **in**, and **I**.

But there can be other 9-letter words that don't fit the specific hints. So far I've found...

> 1. **growlings**. Removing letters gives **growling**, **growing**, **rowing**, **owing**, **wing**, **win**, **in**, and **I**.
>
>  2. **crownings**. Removing letters gives **crowning**, **crowing**, ... *(finish as above)*